# How would you perform this bitwise operation?

Tags: bitmap, bit-manipulation

For a particular application using bitwise masks to store a value, I'd like to perform a certain bitwise filter, but I'm not sure what it's called, or how you'd actually do it in a sensible way.

```
// I'll just refer to the operator as "?" for the sake of example:
Input1 ? Input2 = Output
     0 ? 0      = 0
     0 ? 1      = 0
     1 ? 0      = 1
     1 ? 1      = 0

  101      110      1100
? 111    ? 100    ? 1010
= 000    = 010    = 0100
```

*My language is PHP, but any explanation is welcome.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [PHP bitwise operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

```
$a & ~$b
```

meaning (a AND NOT b)

Answer (score 4):

In C:

```
Input1 & ~Input2
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a single operator

Output = Input1 AND NOT(Input2)